# cloudwatch command get-metric-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

I'm not able to get the metric data through this command.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries jsonfile.json \
   --start-time 2019-02-01T10:40:0000 --end-time 2019-02-27T14:12:0000
```

The following error is getting shown.

```
Error parsing parameter '--metric-data-queries': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
```

jsonfile.json

Here, the jsonfile.json contains my query, defined below.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "MyRequest",
        "MetricStat": {
            "Metric": {
                "Namespace": "AWS/EBS",
                "MetricName": "VolumeReadBytes",
                "Dimensions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "VolumeId",
                        "Value": "vol-******420********"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Period": "3600",
            "Stat": "Average",
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        "Label": "myRequestLabel",
        "ReturnData": "true"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think what you need to run is;

```sh
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --cli-input-json file://jsonfile.json
```

The content of your jsonfile.json should be as follows;

```json
{
    "MetricDataQueries": [
        {
            "Id": "myRequest",
            "MetricStat": {
                "Metric": {
                    "Namespace": "AWS/EBS",
                    "MetricName": "VolumeReadBytes",
                    "Dimensions": [
                        {
                            "Name": "VolumeId",
                            "Value": "vol-******420******"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Period": 3600,
                "Stat": "Average",
                "Unit": "Bytes"
            },
            "Label": "myRequestLabel",
            "ReturnData": true
        }
    ],
    "StartTime": "2019-02-01T10:40:0000",
    "EndTime": "2019-02-27T14:12:0000"
}
```

Comment: I tried this but getting "The parameter MetricDataQueries is required", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461333/cloudwatch-get-metric-data-the-parameter-metricdataqueries-is-required , thanks, Martin

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_time=$(date --utc -d "24 hours ago" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
now=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

aws --output json cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/NetworkELB \
    --metric-name ActiveFlowCount --statistics Sum  --period 3600 \
    --dimensions Name=LoadBalancer,Value=net/YourHash1/YourHash2 \
    --start-time $start_time --end-time $now
```

Comment: Date should be in UTC for AWS: `date --utc -d "24 hours ago" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'.  I recommend removing `/usr/local/bin/` for consistency.