# cloudwatch get-metric-data - The parameter MetricDataQueries is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have as a query, this below, looks ok to me, but for some reason it complains on the data.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries --cli-input-json file://metric-data-query.json --start-time 2023-06-13T00:00:0000 --end-time 2023-06-13T23:59:0000 --region us-east-2
```

metric-data-query.json:

```json
{
    "MetricDataQueries": [
        {
            "Id": "myRequest",
            "MetricStat": {
                "Metric": {
                    "Namespace": "AWS/Lambda",
                    "MetricName": "Errors",
                    "Dimensions": [
                        {
                            "FunctionName": "my-func-name-here"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Label": "myRequestLabel",
            "ReturnData": true
        }
    ],
    "StartTime": "2023-06-13T00:00:0000",
    "EndTime": "2023-06-13T23:59:0000"
}
```

why am I having this as an error? MetricDataQueries IS THERE!

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetMetricData operation: The parameter MetricDataQueries is required.
The parameter MetricDataQueries is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing two different concepts. If you wish to pass *ALL* parameters via a JSON file, then use `--cli-input-json`. However, if you only wish to pass the `MetricDataQueries` via JSON in a file, then use `--metric-data-queries file://metric-data-query.json` like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries file://metric-data-query.json --start-time 2023-06-13T00:00:0000 --end-time 2023-06-13T23:59:0000 --region us-east-2
```

Based on the sample on [get-metric-data — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html), the JSON file should look like:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "string",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "string",
        "MetricName": "string",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "string",
            "Value": "string"
          }
          ...
        ]
      },
      "Period": integer,
      "Stat": "string",
      "Unit": "Seconds"|"Microseconds"|"Milliseconds"|"Bytes"|"Kilobytes"|"Megabytes"|"Gigabytes"|"Terabytes"|"Bits"|"Kilobits"|"Megabits"|"Gigabits"|"Terabits"|"Percent"|"Count"|"Bytes/Second"|"Kilobytes/Second"|"Megabytes/Second"|"Gigabytes/Second"|"Terabytes/Second"|"Bits/Second"|"Kilobits/Second"|"Megabits/Second"|"Gigabits/Second"|"Terabits/Second"|"Count/Second"|"None"
    },
    "Expression": "string",
    "Label": "string",
    "ReturnData": true|false,
    "Period": integer,
    "AccountId": "string"
  }
  ...
]
```

Note that there are several required fields, such as `Period` and `Stat`.